# Foreign key composed from multiple models

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am using mongo and mongoose and I am trying to model my app.
I have the following models: ProductA, ProductB and ProductChat.
Each Product can have many Chats. Each chat is related to one and only product (A or B).
I'd like ProductChat to have a reference to the relevant product document. I thought about adding productType, productId fields to ProductChat:

`const ProductChatSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    ...
    productType: {
        type: 'String',
        required: true,
        enum: [ 'A', 'B' ]
    },
    product: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: '???' // Ref to what?
    },
    ...
    ...
});`

But I don't know what to put on 'ref'...
I'd like to avoid adding productAId, productBId fields on ProductChat because there might be many products.
Any idea how to do it correct?

Answer (score 1):

As there are many products, give ProductChat ref to ProductsA(B, C..) collection in an array.

```
const productA = new Schema({
    ProductChatIds: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'ProductChat'
    }]
});

const productB = new Schema({
    ProductChatIds: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'ProductChat'
    }]
});
```

Comment: This is a problem because given a product chat id, I'd like to get the relevant product.

Comment: Moreover, that way I don't enforce one product per chat.

Comment: Hi Noar. In the above answer, you will notice that ProductChatIds is an array of Object Ids. 

The "ref" is supposed to refer to the name of the model that the ID is supposed to refer to. 

This way, each product can have an array of ProductChats by referencing to their Object IDs.

Answer (score 0):

`ref` field means in which collection the `id` mentioned is gonna be searched for. So, you have to refer to the collection. 
For example:

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    postedBy: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    dateCreated: Date,
    comments: [{body:"string", by: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}],
});
```

Then make your model:

```
var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

Comment: You didn't answer my question